# how to connect to bolt with cypher-shell not on localhost

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Really want to connect to bolt from an spark slave also but figured if I can get it working with cypher-shell the rest will fall into place.  So I can do this:

```
cypher-shell -a localhost
```

Connects fine

if I do this on the box which is the actual ip:

```
cypher-shell -a 172.20.0.71:7687
```

Get a connection refused, I thought all I had to do was in the conf do:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687
```

That didn't seem to work is there something else I am missing?
(Or at least the above didn't seem to work I did restart my neo4j instance so it should of picked up the changes to conf).  Connecting just with defaults on cypher-shell does give this still though:

```
Connected to Neo4j 3.3.0 at bolt://localhost:7687 as user neo4j.
Type :help for a list of available commands or :exit to exit the shell.
Note that Cypher queries must end with a semicolon.
```

So maybe it didn't fully restart and pick up the changes to the `neo4j.conf` ?  Or more likely I am missing something else to get this to work as I think it should.  Where I can connect from another ip or locally to bolt via the actual ip address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to uncomment this in your `neo4j.conf` :

```
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
```

Restart the server, and then with cypher-shell :

```
cypher-shell -a bolt://172.20.0.71:7687
```